# how to delete automatic date if more than 5 minutes using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

> how to delete automatic date if more than 5 minutes

```
$time = 1; 
        $deletetoken = "DELETE FROM log aa LEFT JOIN user bb ON aa.`email`=bb.`email` 
                    WHERE aa.`code_aktivasi`='code_aktivasi' 
                    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), create_at)-> $time";
        $run = mysql_query($deletetoken);
```

I want automatic date if more than 5 minutes, 
But it is not working, what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion, hoping it helps you to solve the problem.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM log l LEFT JOIN user u ON l.`email`= u.`email` 
                    WHERE l.`code_aktivasi`='code_aktivasi' and `create_at` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";

$run = mysql_query($sql);
```

You can use `l.create_at` or `u.create_at` for matching your purpose.

If it's still not working, please show me the error message.

Comment: create_at = timestamp, I try first,,

Comment: what dis you mean?